# Plotly bar chart is not visible clearly?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I am using plotly to visualize dataset using bar chart but the chart is not visible clearly.

Here is my code:
`fig = px.bar(data, x="Month", y="AQI",color="AQI Category",  barmode='group') fig.show()`

Here is the output:
[Barchart in Plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqRCB.png)

Can anyone please explain why the bar chart is not clearly shown?

I search everywhere but couldn't found solution

Comment: Is the month on the x-axis numerical or time series, or would changing the x-axis type to category improve it? `fig.update_xaxes(type='category')`

Answer (score 0):

Insert before `fig.show.()`:

> fig.update_traces(
> opacity = 1,
> template = "plotly_white"
> )